# Error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React2.useContext(...)' as it is null"

Tags: reactjs, three.js, tailwind-css

I'm facing

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React2.useContext(...)' as it is null.

In the `Link` component of the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { styles } from '../styles';
import { navLinks } from '../constansts';
import { logo, menu, close } from '../assets';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('');
  return (
    <nav className={`${styles.paddingX} w-full flex items-center py-5 fixed top-0 z-20     bg-primary`}>
      <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center max-w-7x1 max-auto">
        <Link
          to="/"
          className="flex items-center gap-2"
          onClick={() => {
            setActive('');
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
          }}
        >
          <img alt="logo" />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: where you are using the useContext() hook?

Comment: move this Nav component to be within the `<BrowserRouter>`, before `<Routes>` tag. I just couldn't find yet the reason why the Link component must be within BrowserRouter, maybe it is the only way react can handle the page navigation and switch one at a time.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You're using `Link` from `react-router-dom`, which is calling `useContext`. The context it is looking for is provided by `BrowserRouter`, but your app is not wrapped by a  `BrowserRouter`. Your `index.js`:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: what is the explanation for this?

Comment: @JuniorMayhé it's because the react-router-dom `Link` implementation is calling `useContext` and the context it is looking for is provided by `BrowserRouter`

Comment: We migrated to createBrowserRouter recently and this stopped working and the issue on this question is popping up. Our whole app is wrapper inside this router. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I just imported `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';` and added `return (
    <Router>
    ...
    </Router>`

and the error went away

Comment: Can you add the explanation to the answer, please? (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 7):

Be sure to use routing properly in *App.js* and put the navbar component inside the BrowserRouter. As an example, let's pretend that your *app.js* looks similar to:

```
function App() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
        <Route path="/x" element={<x/>}/>
        <Route path="/y" element={<y/>}/>
        <Route path="/z" element={<z/>}/>
        <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </div>);
}

export default App;
```

then:

```
 function App() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <NavBar/>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
        <Route path="/x" element={<x/>}/>
        <Route path="/y" element={<y/>}/>
        <Route path="/z" element={<z/>}/>
        <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </div>);
}

export default App;
```

Be sure to also add the import!

Before wrapping the routes, I imported BrowserRouter as Router, because it helps me to understand the code. That's why it's declared like that.

Comment: Is it "app.js" or "App.js"?