# Can't use React link inside component with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router

My React app has an `Item` component that should redirect users to the `App` component by clicking a button inside a `react-router-dom` `Link` component. I've followed lots of tutorials that have given clear examples of how to implement `Link` inside components that don't pass props. My guts tell me that my `Item` component props might be causing the `Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React__namespace.useContext(...)' as it is null.]` error because running tests on Jest are only possible when `Link` is not present in the code.

**What I tried**

- Moved the `RouteSwitch` code to index.js
- Moved the scripts that live in the `components` to `src`
- Double-checked that I followed the tutorials correctly
- Saw if this [reactjs - Uncaught TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728532/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-basename-of-react2-usecontext) StackOverFlow answer is related to my problem

Can anybody point out what I'm missing here please?

*item.js*

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Item = ({info},{addCart}) => {

  return(
    <>
      <Link to="/" ><button>X</button></Link>
      <img src={info.pic} alt={info.title}></img>
      <h1>{info.title}</h1>
      <p>{info.description}</p>
      <button onClick={()=>{addCart(info)}}>Add</button>
    </>
  )
};

export default Item;
```

*routeswitch.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App"

const RouteSwitch = () =>{
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default RouteSwitch;
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import RouteSwitch from "./routeswitch"
import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouteSwitch/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

*item.test.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup,screen, getByAltText} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Item from './item';

afterEach(cleanup);
const details = {pic: `a pic`, title:`a title`, description:`a description`}
const addCartMock =jest.fn(); 

test(`Content renders`,()=>{
  render(<Item info={details} addCart={addCartMock}/>);

  const image = screen.getByAltText(`${details.title}`);
  expect(image).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(image).toHaveAttribute(`src`,`${details.pic}`);
  expect(screen.getByRole(`heading`, {name:details.title})).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByText(`${details.description}`)).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByRole(`button`, {name: `Add`})).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test(`Add button click event`,()=>{
  render(<Item info={details} addCart={addCartMock(details)}/>);

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole(`button`), {name: `Add`});
  expect(addCartMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(details);
});
```

Comment: Does it happen only in tests?

Comment: Typo in the `Item` component accessing the props, `const Item = ({info},{addCart}) => {` should be `const Item = ({info, addCart}) => {`... there is only one props object to destructure properties from. Another typo in the test, `addCart={addCartMock(details)}` immediately calls the function, you probably want `addCart={() => addCartMock(details)}`. Other than this it is unclear what any `Link` component has to do with anything in the post.

Comment: I wondered that as well @Konrad and thanks to Drew Reese's answer below, I could confirm that the bug was actually the test. Thanks for suggesting that anyway!

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese! Definitely I didn't write the props in the right way. In fact your comment made me realize that I had a different idea of how props worked in my head. Glad that happened to get better at props. BTW when I put the `addCartMock` inside an arrow function my `expect(addCartMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(details)` stopped working. I'm gonna check what's going on there more in depth

Comment: Oh @DrewReese! Link is aimed to be a button (X) that takes you back to the store main page.

Comment: Last thing `addCart={()=>addCartMock(details)}` now lives in the test code to void immediate function call. I had to change its test into `async` to be able to "click" on the button with `await userEvent.click(screen.queryByText(`Add`));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the `Link` in the unit tests is that it requires a routing context to be provided to it. Import the `MemoryRouter` and render the component into it so the `Link` component has a routing context available to it.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup, screen, getByAltText } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Item from './item';

afterEach(cleanup);

const details = {
  pic: "a pic",
  title: "a title",
  description: "a description",
};
const addCartMock = jest.fn(); 

test("Content renders", () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Item info={details} addCart={addCartMock} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  const image = screen.getByAltText(`${details.title}`);
  expect(image).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(image).toHaveAttribute("src",`${details.pic}`);
  expect(screen.getByRole("heading", { name: details.title })).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByText(`${details.description}`)).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(screen.getByRole("button", { name: `Add` })).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test("Add button click event", () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Item info={details} addCart={() => addCartMock(details)} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"), { name: "Add" });
  expect(addCartMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(details);
});
```

You've also an issue accessing the props object in the `Item` component. There is only a single props object passed to React components and all props are destructured from it.

```
const Item = ({ info, addCart }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="/"><button>X</button></Link>
      <img src={info.pic} alt={info.title} />
      <h1>{info.title}</h1>
      <p>{info.description}</p>
      <button onClick={()=>{addCart(info)}}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew! I was hesitant to include the test code in the question but deep inside I was aware that there might've been an issue with the test rather than the code. Learned today that test need also a context which makes sense in order to simulate what I'm rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what is causing the challenge, but in your `item.js` you are destructuring the props wrongly. you can either desructure it directly, or take the props and use dot notations to get its children:

```
const Item = ({info, addCart}) => {

  return(
    <>
      // rest of your code
    </>
  )
};
```

OR

```
const Item = (props) => {

  return(
    <>
      <Link to="/" ><button>X</button></Link>
      <img src={props.info.pic} alt={props.info.title}></img>
      <h1>{props.info.title}</h1>
      <p>{props.info.description}</p>
      <button onClick={()=>{props.addCart(info)}}>Add</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

OR

```
const Item = (props) => {
  const {info, addCart} = props
  return(
    <>
      <Link to="/" ><button>X</button></Link>
      <img src={info.pic} alt={info.title}></img>
      <h1>{info.title}</h1>
      <p>{info.description}</p>
      <button onClick={()=>{addCart(info)}}>Add</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

Comment: Thanks Izebeafe! Your contribution is not the answer this time but as I commented above in my question section comments. I realized I had a wrong idea of how props worked so it was good to get your comment and Drew's to noticed that there was something else to be improved in my code.