# How can I solve this React Router Dom Link tag error?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-dom

[[[Main.jsx, Navbar.jsx and Bowser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kisMH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzr8u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJgVI.png)

When I add "Link" tag then show this error. Please solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728532/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-basename-of-react2-usecontext

Comment: Haven't solution. This is old version