# React Redux Testing Provider Wrap

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

Can anyone help with my tests for a React App with Redux store. I based my project on the counter Redux example app which cam with the below App.test.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './app/store';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  expect(getByText(/learn/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
 });
```

When I run the test it gives the error:

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of
> 'React__namespace.useContext(...)' as it is null.

I think this is because my app is getting data from Reddit API so nothing in store until this data is returned.

The above App.test.js test works on the Redux example project which I think is because the store in that example has fixed values to begin with.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Header  from './features/Header/Header';
import { Posts } from './features/Posts/Posts';
import { SubReddit } from './features/Subreddit/SubReddit';
import { Comments } from './features/Comments/Comments';
import Footer  from './features/Footer/Footer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div className='homePage'>
        <SubReddit />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Posts />} />
          <Route path="/Comments" element={<Comments />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import postsReducer from '../features/Posts/postsSlice';
import subRedditReducer from 
'../features/Subreddit/subRedditSlice';
import commentsReducer from '../features/Comments/commentsSlice';

export const store = configureStore({ 
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    subReddits: subRedditReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you share the content of your App.js, as well as your store ?

Comment: App.js and store.js added to post. Cheers

Comment: 'which I think is because the store in that example has fixed values to begin with' - and how were *you* intending to initialize the mock context, instead?

Comment: This is what I need advice with I think. My redux store has a lot of data in the store. Do I need to mock it in each slice the same as if it fetched it from the API? 
This is the first time I have done any testing, struggling a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's related to the usage of `react-router-dom`.

If you wanna use `<Routes>`, your `<App>` should be wrapped in a Router, like `<BrowserRouter/`>, like so :

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75728680/1489088

Also : https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router

Comment: Already have this in index.js. Cheers

Comment: Would this effect the test. The app is working fine?  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `App` is rendering some components that require a routing context that is provided by one of the `react-router-dom` router components. `App` works in your regular code because you are likely wrapping it in a router, but in the unit test it is not.

Generally in non-DOM environments, like Node.js, where you are running your tests you can't, or shouldn't, use the `BrowserRouter`. In unit testing you can use the [`MemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router).

> A `<MemoryRouter>` stores its locations internally in an array. Unlike
> `<BrowserHistory>` and `<HashHistory>`, it isn't tied to an external
> source, like the history stack in a browser. ***This makes it ideal
> for scenarios where you need complete control over the history stack,
> like testing***.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { store } from './app/store';
import App from './App';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <App />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  expect(getByText(/learn/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

If you need to specify being on any specific route then use the `initialEntries` and `initialIndex` props. For example, if you had an `App` test that needed to be on the `"/comments"` path use the following:

```
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/", "/comments"]}>
  ...
</MemoryRouter>
```

FWIW I don't see where `App` is rendering a link with the text "learn", so I suspect you are testing too much in this specific test. I suspect the "learn" link is rendered in the `Header` and should probably be tested with that component's unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeh learn was in the template. I changed that to some text that was in the App.js.  MemoryRouter worked and passed the tests but threw another error about abandoning test (or similar). I am struggling with testing redux now. I have asked a new question on here. Cheers