# Cannot destructure property 'basename' React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am  beginner of the react when i implemented the react router i ran into the problem with **Cannot destructure property 'basename' React**
what i tried so far i attached below.lets look at the code below.

```
import Employee from './components/employee';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Task from './components/task';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tutusfunny</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                

                  <Link to="/employee" className="btn btn-primary">Employee</Link>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <Link to="/task" className="btn btn-primary">Task</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Employee />
              <Routes>
                
                <Route path="/" element={<Employee />} />
                <Route path="/task" element={<Task />}>
                </Route>
              </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
 </div>       
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React2.useContext(...)' as it is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75728532/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-basename-of-react2-usecontext) In short: the problem could be that you are using `<Link>` outside of `<BrowserRouter>`.

Comment: i went through that article but couldn't solve the problem

Comment: I extended my comment